# How to find out Python function definition with Regular Expression vscode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I want to find python function definition and body part

**What i have tried:**
My expression: `^((?:[\s]{0,4})*)def[ ].*[\(].*[\)][:](\n.*\s)\1.*`
as you can see in image expression is not accurate, specifically ending part.
any Regex expert would like to suggest something? Thanks!

[image: VSCode Editor]

**Example Text:**

```
def func1():
    print("line")
    print("line")
    print("line")

def func2(self, vals):
    print("line")

    print("line")
    print("line")

class cls1(cls2):

    def method1(self):
        print("line")
        print("line")
        print("line")
        print("line")

    def method2(self):
        def inner():
            print("line")
        print("line")
```

Comment: Could you please copy the python code that you test your regular expression against into your question as text?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin Sure! its Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression can help you:
`(?P<indent>[ \t]*)def[ \t]*(?P<name>\w+)\s*\((?P<params>.*?)\)(?:[ \t]*->[ \t]*(?P<return>\w+))?:(?P<body>(?:\n(?P=indent)(?:[ \t]+[^\n]*)|\n)+)`.

Parts of the function definition will be captured as `name`, `params`, `return` and `body`.

Note the backreference `(?P=indent)`. Together with the following `(?:[ \t]+`, it is used to make sure that the function body is indented from the function signature by at least one space or tab. Only lines indented so or empty will be consumed as function body.

https://regex101.com/r/WWUa8A/4.

Comment: its working I don't know why you got one dislike but yes it breaks when the function has empty lines like I update in my question "func2". so ya its not your fault. 
I am trying to fix that meanwhile if you find-out please update. Thank you so much for your efforts. (Upvote for me)

Comment: @MohitGhodasara see the updated answer. If it suits you, you may want to *accept* it.

Comment: it's working as expected. can you please explain last part how it will decide that it is end of an function body? Thanks again

Comment: @MohitGhodasara,  see the end of the updated answer.